# @JoinColumn referencedColumnName specified value is ignored when used with collectionTable

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have configuration as I mentioned below and here I am expecting collection table joincolumn (foriegn key) should point to Subclass primarykey

Configuration:

```
@DependencySubclasses({LookupTypeOne.class, LookupTypeTwo.class})
@CodeReview(status = ReviewStatus.PENDING, reviewer = "")
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOOKUP_TABLE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractLookup {

@GsonExclude
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = UID_GENERATOR)
@Column(name = "LOOKUP_ID")
protected Long lookupId;
//.......
}

@CodeReview(status = CodeReview.ReviewStatus.PENDING, reviewer = "")
@Entity
@Table(name = LOOKUP_CURVE_TABLE)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "LOOKUP_CURVE_ID")
public class LookupTypeOne extends AbstractLookup {

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "COLLECTION_TABLE", joinColumns =   @JoinColumn(name = "CT_LT_ID", referencedColumnName = "LOOKUP_CURVE_ID", nullable = false))
private List<ParameterTableColumn> varyByParameterItems = Lists.newArrayList();

//...........

}

@Embeddable
public class ParameterTableColumn {
@Dependency(DEFINITION)
private Long columnObjectId;
//.......
}
```

so in LookupTypeOne implementation for collection table joinColumn (foriegn key) I want to refer to "Lookup_CURVE_ID" i.e. primary key of LookupTypeOne and it should work as referencedColumnName = "LOOKUP_CURVE_ID" is specified but still this refere to id of AbstractLookup i.e. "LOOKUP_ID"

From configuration this should work I think but its not working properly. It will be of great help if someone can point whats going wrong and what would be involved to make it refer to "LOOKUP_CURVE_ID".

**So the question here is that why referencedColumnName = "LOOKUP_CURVE_ID" is not making any difference and seems ignored ?**

Comment: *its not working properly*: please elaborate. what doesn't work? How doesn't it work? What code do you execute, what do you expect it to do and what does it do instead, precisely?

Comment: Based on above configuration  mentioned
**Expected** is that in collection table Join column (CT_LT_ID) it should refer to LOOKUP_CURVE_ID but
**Actual** it refer to LOOKUP_ID

Comment: And Code exceute is to simply merge (entityManager.merge) the LookupTypeOne entity with List<ParameterTableColumn> in it.

Please let me know if the question/context still not clear.

Comment: LOOKUP_CURVE_ID is a foreign key to LOOKUP_ID, so what's the difference? They have the same value.